# I am not able to insert a document to my remote DB server getting error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication'

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

As per log iam able to connect to my remote Mongo server 
using following code:

```
String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, 
 userDB, password);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new 
ServerAddress(vars.get("mongohost"), vars.get("mongoPort") as int)))}
.build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

but when Iam inserting a document,getting following error:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command 
failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication' 
on server 10.80.47.101:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": 
"command insert requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": 
"Unauthorized"}
```

note that I am using same authentication credentials to insert a document through NOSQLbooster and its successful.

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots from errormessage, but add the text to the question.  The screenshot is not searchable/copyable/...

Comment: You're not using credentials...

Comment: @tim_yates to my knowledge this is how i should be using credentials.if u think its not right how should i do that?kindly guide

Comment: The variable `credential` is not used in your code.  I have never used Mongo but I find it hard to believe the builder(?) there manipulates some global state and the client uses it.

Comment: Add it to the settings object with `.credential(credential)`

Comment: As shown in the docs https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver-async/tutorials/authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an instance of [MongoCredential](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/MongoCredential.html) but not using them in the [MongoClientSettings](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.html) (at least I fail to see it), you need to pass it to the [MongoClientSettings.Builder.credential](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.Builder.html#credential-com.mongodb.MongoCredential-) function

More simple authentication example can be found in the [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user:password@mongohost/?authSource=userdb&ssl=true");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the following code, I was able to connect to Mongo DB with authentication!

```
String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
MongoCredential credential = 
MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, userDB, 
password);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new 
ServerAddress(vars.get("mongohost"), vars.get("mongoPort") as 
int)))}
.credential(credential)
.build();

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```